# Set DarkMode on the first page status bar xamarin forms android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Using xamarin forms and we are adding ability to switch between Dark-Light mode. All is good however the first page of the app in android whatever I do the status bar color wont change.

I guess that in the android project I have to call SetTheme(...) before OnCreate.

Or Am I missing something here?

Question
How do you set the status bar color depending on theme? code below does not change once the android has loaded

```
        public void SetStatusBarColor(System.Drawing.Color color, bool darkStatusBarTint)
    {
        var activity = Platform.CurrentActivity;
        var window = activity.Window;
        window?.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
        window?.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
        window?.SetStatusBarColor(color.ToPlatformColor());

        var flag = (StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.LightStatusBar;
        if (window != null)
        {
            window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = darkStatusBarTint ? flag : 0;
        }
    }
```

Suggestions?
thanks

Comment: usually statusbar color on Android is set based on the `colorPrimaryDark`, maybe try to chage it, also on the `NavigationPage BarBackgroundColor` property from xamarin forms you set the statusbar color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
private void SetStatusBarColor(System.Drawing.Color color, bool darkStatusBarTint)
{
    var activity = Platform.CurrentActivity;
    var window = activity.Window;

    if (window != null)
    {
        window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
        window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
        window.SetStatusBarColor(color.ToPlatformColor());
        
        StatusBarVisibility flags = default;

        if (darkStatusBarTint)
            flags |= (StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.LightStatusBar;
        else
            flags &= ~(StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.LightStatusBar;

        window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = flags;
    }
}
```

Or

```
private void SetStatusBarColor(System.Drawing.Color color, bool darkStatusBarTint)
{
    var activity = Platform.CurrentActivity;
    var window = activity.Window;

    if (window != null)
    {
        window.AddFlags(WindowManagerFlags.DrawsSystemBarBackgrounds);
        window.ClearFlags(WindowManagerFlags.TranslucentStatus);
        window.SetStatusBarColor(color.ToPlatformColor());

        window.DecorView.SystemUiVisibility = darkStatusBarTint
            ? (StatusBarVisibility)SystemUiFlags.LightStatusBar
            : StatusBarVisibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Both functions work.

You can update the StatusBar color in the `MainActivity.OnCreate` method and also listen to the `App.Current.RequestedThemeChanged` event.

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
        
        ApplyStatusBarColor(App.Current.RequestedTheme);
        App.Current.RequestedThemeChanged += (s, e) => ApplyStatusBarColor(e.RequestedTheme);
    }

    private void ApplyStatusBarColor(Xamarin.Forms.OSAppTheme osAppTheme)
    {
        if (osAppTheme == Xamarin.Forms.OSAppTheme.Dark)
            SetStatusBarColor(Xamarin.Forms.Color.Blue, false);
        else
            SetStatusBarColor(Xamarin.Forms.Color.Yellow, true);
    }
}
```